# How to reset profile file on linux?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have got an Amazon EC2 instance. I edited `etc/profile`, which has resulted in something terrible. Now, I am not able to connect to the instance from `Filezilla`. I am able to connect through `putty` but the terminal opens with lot of text. I am definitely sure this is all because of something accidental changes that I created in `profile`.

Is there any way I can reset `etc/profile` to its earlier version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to revert to the previous version if you dont have a backup of the file / snapshot of the instance ...

Depends if you already made change but if you want the default version, you can spin up a new ec2 instance of the same type, copy the `/etc/profile` from the new instance into your current instance. All this can be done within an hour so it will cost you only 1 hour of an additional ec2 instance.

Comment: Things should work if I just undo the changes made earlier, right?

Comment: yes also .. If you know your change and undo them its ok